# Require method arguments to implement multiple interfaces in C#

Tags: c#, interface, intersection-types

The code below is a minimal example I wrote to illustrate my question.
I think it's more useful than me trying to explain the situation in words.

I also removed all references to WPF, ICommand, IDisposable, etc, because I want to discourage answers and comments that ask me "Why don't you just use Prism or some other random library?!"
I'm asking questions because I want to learn more about the language and have noone to talk to in real life.

```cs
public interface IRedDependency { }
public interface IBlueDependency { }

public interface IExecutable {
  public void Execute();
}
public interface IStoppable {
  public void Stop();
}

public class RedExecutable : IExecutable, IStoppable {
  public RedExecutable(IRedDependency redDependency) { }
  public void Execute() { }
  public void Stop() { }
}
public class BlueExecutable : IExecutable, IStoppable {
  public BlueExecutable(IBlueDependency blueDependency) { }
  public void Execute() { }
  public void Stop() { }
}

public class Example {
  public Example(
    IRedDependency redDependency,
    IBlueDependency blueDependency)
  {
    RedExecutable = RememberToStopExecutable(
      new RedExecutable(redDependency));

    BlueExecutable = RememberToStopExecutable(
      new BlueExecutable(blueDependency));
  }

  public IExecutable RedExecutable { get; }
  public IExecutable BlueExecutable { get; }
  private readonly List<IStoppable> _stoppables = new();

  private IExecutable RememberToStopExecutable(IStoppable stoppable) {
    _stoppables.Add(stoppable);
    return (IExecutable)stoppable;
  } 
  
  public void Stop() {
    foreach (IStoppable stoppable in _stoppables) {
      stoppable.Stop();  
    }
  } 
  
}
```

It does what I expect it to do.

But I don't like the fact that I have to do an explicit cast from `IStoppable` to `IExecutable` in `RememberToStopExecutable`, because I can't be sure, that the `IStoppable` I pass to the method also implements `IExecutable`.

One idea I had was to define an Interface `IExecutableAndStoppable` which inherits from both `IExecutable` and `IStoppable`, in the hopes that I could use this Interface as the type of the `stoppable` parameter. Unfortunately this doesn't work, because the IDE says one can't

Here is the not valid code anywasy:
The valid code for the Interface:

```cs
public interface IExecutableAndStoppable : IExecutable, IStoppable {}
```

with the valid code for the method:

```cs
private IExecutable RememberToStopExecutable(
    IExecutableAndStoppable stoppable)
{
  _stoppables.Add(stoppable);
  return stoppable;
}
```

but the code where I call the method is not valid anymore:

```cs
RedExecutable = RememberToStopExecutable(
  new RedExecutable(redDependency));
```

because, as the IDE says:

> Arugment type `RedExecutable` is not assignable to parameter type `IExecutableAndStoppable`.

which is not obvious to me, since `IExecutableAndStoppable` inherits from both `IExecutable` and `IStoppable`, but so does `RedExecutable`.

**Solution Attempt 1**
Sure, I could make `RedExecutable` and `BlueExecutable` also implement `IExecutableAndStoppable` like this:

```cs
public class RedExecutable : IExecutable, IStoppable, IExecutableAndStoppable { /*code*/ }
```

in which case my IDE even tells me:

> Base interfaces IExecutable and IStoppable are redundant because RedExecutable already implements IExecutableAndStoppable

so I can simply write:

```cs
public class RedExecutable : IExecutableAndStoppable { /*code*/ }
public class BlueExecutable : IExecutableAndStoppable { /*code*/ }
```

Then it's all good.

**Solution Attempt 2**
But what if I don't really want to make this change to `RedExecutable` and `BlueExecutable` just for the one use-case where I want to pass them into my small private method `RememberToStopExecutable`? Maybe there could be situation where I for whatever reason can't simply change the code of `RedExecutable` and `BlueExecutable`.

Then I could maybe make the method `RememberToStopExecutable` take two parameters, one of type `IExecutable` the other of type `IStoppable`, but pass the same object to both.
I'd keep `RedExecutable` and `BlueExecutable` as they were originally, i.e.

```cs
public class RedExecutable : IExecutable, IStoppable { /*code*/ }
public class BlueExecutable : IExecutable, IStoppable { /*code*/ }
```

and write

```cs
private IExecutable RememberToStopExecutable(
  IExecutable executable,
  IStoppable stoppable)
{
  _stoppables.Add(stoppable);
  return executable;
}
```

Then I could do this:

```cs
RedExecutable redExecutable = new RedExecutable(redDependency);
RedExecutable = RememberToStopExecutable(redExecutable, redExecutable);
```

but well, this looks pretty weird because I'd have to pass the same object to both parameters and because I need to define a temporary variable `redExecutable`.

**Question**
Is there no way around using type-casts in this situation?
I feel like I surely must be missing some super trivial and obvious asnwer here.

All I want is to be able to write a function like the origianl

```cs
private IExecutable RememberToStopExecutable(IStoppable stoppable) {
  _stoppables.Add(stoppable);
  return (IExecutable)stoppable;
}
```

just without the weird type-casting.

Like, just have a method that expects arguments that implement both of two interfaces. Then allow the allow the function to treat the argument as if it's implementing either of the interfaces. How can I do that?

I googled and this might be related to Intersection-Types which C# doesn't have. So how to people do this in C# ?

Comment: Can `IStoppable` implement `IExecutable` (`public interface IStoppable : IExecutable`)? After all, if it can `Stop()`, is has to have started to `Execute()`. Unless there's a pattern you can think of that where you can `Stop()` without starting.

Comment: I'm assuming the interfaces `IExecutable` and `IStoppable` already exist and are not changable. I understand the reasoning behind them having to be started before being stopped, but they are actually just random names I came up with. They don't have meaning. I could have picked `public interface IOne` with method `public void MethodOne();` and `public interface ITwo` with method `public void MethodTwo();` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make your method generic, with type constraints such that the single object passed in must be both executable and stoppable:

```
private IExecutable RememberToStopExecutable<T>(T stoppable)
where T : IStoppable, IExecutable
{
    _stoppables.Add(stoppable);
    return stoppable;
}
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for.
I like, that I can even still call it without specifying `T`, becauses the compiler can infer it from the arguments I pass in at compile time, [is what the docs say](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-methods).

I also like, that I could still pass an instance of a class implementing `IExecutableAndStoppable` if I wanted to.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

If you can make the restriction that if your class is `IStoppable`, then it is also `IExecutable`, then you could make `IStoppable` inherit from `IExecutable`.

```
interface IStoppable : IExecutable
{
    void Stop();
}
```

If you cannot make this restriction, then you can make a safe cast from `IExecutable` to `IStoppable` and then test if the cast succeeded.

```
var stoppable = executable as IStoppable;
if (stoppable != null)
{
    _stoppables.Add(stoppable);
}
```

or using pattern matching:

```
if (executable is IStoppable stoppable)
{
    _stoppables.Add(stoppable);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Though it's still using casts, even if they are safe casts or pattern matching. That's why I picked the other answer as 'accepted', because it's more what I had in mind when asking the question. Still, thank you very much. It's appreciated